# How can I set the trackpad preferences in OS X Snow Leopard using a script?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, touchpad, system-preferences

I'm using 10.6 Snow Leopard and the Better Touch Tool (redefine trackpad functions, etc). I have a that when I restart several options in the trackpad system preference pane revert to OS X defaults. I'm not sure what causes this, but I'd like to be able to restore them to the way I want with something like defaults.write if possible.

The yellow ones are the ones which need to be inverted. The shown state is correct. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Or, if this is not possible, does anybody have an idea of why these things keep reverting to their default state? I just asked how to change them back as I thought it would be less trouble to take that approach.

Comment: Manually? By opening System Preferences and clicking the checkmarks of course!

Comment: I don't know about 10.6, but on 10.7 most of the preferences are stored in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist` and a few in `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`.

Comment: @Lri They still must be reloaded somehow. It's not a preference that can be reloaded by restarting an application, is it?

Comment: probably just killing the dock. that works for everything else. jk ;)

Comment: @DanielBeck Actually I don't think you can ever edit the preferences in `com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist` directly on Lion.

Comment: Any ideas on what I should do to troubleshoot why this is happening?